# Books about business and Torah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally, business

Friends regularly ask me for recommendations of great Torah books for business people, focused on *halakha* or *hashkafa*, as inspiration for people straddling the line between a busy professional life and commitment to Torah.

I thought my answer might be helpful to others so sharing below - and would be eager for additional ideas to make this stronger.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1958542105 haven't read but looks like a promising table of contents

Answer (score 5):

I really liked the following books on the intersection of Torah and business life

- Naftali Horowitz's [You Revealed](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1422627462/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_GWGYPYYBG842E90H8DJT): the author is a very successful banker who shares a Torah perspective on working for a living and includes Torah-based recipes for success in business
- R Aaron Lopiansky's [Orchos Chaim: Ben Torah For Life](https://www.eshelpublications.com/store/p11/Orchos_Chaim%3A_Ben_Torah_For_Life.html): originally written for yeshiva students leaving to work, but really an excellent Torah perspective on balancing working for a living with remaining a *ben Torah*
- Ari Wasserman's Making It Work - [A Practical Guide to Halacha in the Workplace](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1680250310/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_C3NACV3A8XGEYHXH1KBS) (and its [version for women](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1680254081/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_K6JJECNHFHF7YKKARXTT)): a *halacha* book of how Jewish law applies to the myriad situations faced in the workplace
- Yisroel Besser's [Building for Eternity](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/REICH.html) - The Life and Legacy of Reb Moshe Reichmann: the story of a man who achieved excellence in both Torah, the business world and became the largest giver to Torah causes of his time

Answer (score 3):

- In a similar mould to the recent sefer produced about Reb Moshe Reichmann, Artscroll also published by the famed author Rabbi Nachman Seltzer an autobiography of Reb Getzel Berger who was essentially the UK equivalent of Moshe Reichmann. The sefer is entitled [Reb Getzel](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422628515.html).
- Feldheim have a sefer entitled *[Faith at Work: Elevating Our Work Day Parashah By Parashah](https://www.feldheim.com/faith-at-work)* - The blurb there reads as follows:

> Does this sound familiar to you? If it does, don't worry, you are not alone!
>
> Many of us in the workplace have probably said or felt like saying these or similar things from time to time. But why? Aren't we all Orthodox, God-fearing, believing Jews?
>
> With Faith at Work, you will discover that you can be in control over these reactions. Weekly inspiration from the parashah and real-life stories from the workplace will help you strengthen your emunah, gain yishuv ha'daas, and turn your career, profession, or business into a spiritual endeavor - ensuring that you are living and making a living the way you should be!

- There is also *[Earning a Living, Earning a Life](https://www.feldheim.com/authors/chaim-kramer/earning-a-living-earning-a-life)* which is a guide by Rav Nachman of Breslov. The blurb writes:

> In this eye-opening book, Rebbe Nachman takes us all the way back to the Kabbalistic origins of Creation to explore the irresistible appeal of money, the reason everyone must work for it, and the forces that try to prevent us from achieving our goals.
>
> He also explains how to stay honest in a world filled with temptations and dishonesty, avoid worry, and budget time and personal obligations as well as finances.

- There is also a title by Artscroll called *[To Be a Mentch](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422617557.html)* which has a chapter (15) called 'Business with Integrity' which like the title suggests is a good primer on interpersonal skills in the workplace.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this book described as wisdom of the ancients for moderns written an by Michael Eisenberg an Israeli Venture Capitalist
[The Tree of Life and Prosperity: 21st Century Business Principles from the Book of Genesis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1637580703)

Comment: Thanks I saw it and Michael is a friend. It is a bit different though, it is a set of commentaries on the weekly parasha, inspired by the world of economics. Very interesting but not so much halacha or hashkafa

Comment: Your welcome, That's very cool! I definitely see your perspective.  However Amazon actually puts it in the business ethics category current #111 on Amazon in that category. I think it can give people perspective on how to apply Torah principles to various business situations.